# Get yarn cache dir error: Command failed: yarn config get enableGlobalCache

Tags: reactjs, vite, hadoop-yarn

my vite app is not loading and there is no error only a warning
[vite] Get yarn cache dir error: Command failed: yarn config get enableGlobalCache

VITE v5.2.5  ready in 1271 ms

➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
➜  Network: use --host to expose
➜  press h + enter to show help

i want a solution of it and make my app running